# Angular 2 Absolute URL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, angular, webpack-dev-server

I want to have a Rails server load an Angular 2 app, so I don't have to run 2 servers.

As an Angular 2 starting point I've used the following example: https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter

If I have the Rails server running, and serve up the index page, the Angular 2 app loads as expected. There's a couple links Home, Dashboard and Todo. They all work when clicked.

If I were to call `http://localhost:3000:/todo` directly then I get a routing error. So, to address the issue I have the following in my rails router:

`get ':todo', controller: :home,  action: :index`

This will load the app, but will not bring me to the 'todo' component.

Now, if I run the Angular 2 app with the webpack-dev-server (as per the repo's instruction) this problem doesn't exist.

It would seem as though the webpack-dev-server is able to redirect all requests to / in such a way that allows Angular 2's routing to take over and direct users to the correct component.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that while I was using the same code to test with both servers I had an individual index file for each server.

The Rails server index file was missing the following line:

`<base href="/">`

After adding that the problem was solved.

Comment: What method did you use to integrate angular 2 and rails?